# Type hinting: Expected `Union[ndarray, Iterable, int float]`, got `Type[ndarray]` instead

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray, type-hinting

Using static type checking on

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def c(x: pd.DataFrame) -> np.ndarray:
    return x.values
```

gives me
`Expected 'Union[ndarray, Iterable, int, float]', got 'Type[ndarray]' instead`.

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: where is your return type?

Comment: @mightyandweakcoder This is just a minimal working example -- the static hinting tool reads the "type" comment and throws the error on that. However, if you insist, you get the same when you pass `x.values` to, e.g. `np.linalg.cholesky` and return that

Comment: Or more simply, if you add `-> np.ndarray` to the function and `return x.values`

Comment: what type checker are you using?

Comment: @AnthonySottile not sure, I'm using PyCharm Professional 2020.1

Comment: sounds like a pycharm bug then, I can't reproduce anything like the error message you're seeing with mypy

Comment: @AnthonySottile You were right -- I thought this was all standard library stuff, but it turns out if I do the checking with mypy and data-science-types (both installed via pip) I get no such error